# How can I block/allow access to document.styleSheets information, and what is the reason for this

Tags: javascript, css

I recently found about [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) API which allows to get stylesheets used by the site.

The use is straightforward and `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` for example will give me all the css rules for the first stylesheet on the page. So when I write this in console in google.com, it returns me a correct list, but when I write in in console on stackoverflow page, it returns `null`.

I assume that some sites can block this information. My questions are:

- how can I block/allow this as a site owner.
- what is the reason for blocking it? (Anyone who would like to get it, can get it by copying the stylesheet and parsing it)

P.S. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398198/document-stylesheeti-returns-null-information-when-location-of-stylesheet-is-r) looks similar, but it is not. I am not looking how to overcome the problem, I am looking the reason and how can I block allow this as an owner. I also have doubts that this is cross-origin problem.

P.P.S. Here is a proof that I get `null` and it is strange that some people did not get null. [image]

Comment: I dont get NULL on stack overflow.

Comment: How do you test code on stackoverflow?

Comment: I updated my question with clarifications.

Comment: @ValentinMercier here is a proof that I have `null`. Do not understand why do you have something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I also have doubts that this is cross-origin problem.

It **is** a cross-origin issue. The reason access is prevented is that the console's origin is derived from the page's URL (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128165/how-can-i-block-allow-access-to-document-stylesheets-information-and-what-is-th` for example), but the URL of the first stylesheet on Stack Overflow (as of this writing) is `http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=d75250aa015c` — a different origin. So programmatic access is denied.

If you tried that in Firefox+FireBug, you'd get a *(slightly)* clearer message: `Error: The operation is insecure.`

On your own site, you're probably serving the CSS from the same origin, so the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) doesn't come into play. If you want the same result as Stack Overflow, serve the CSS from a different origin (it can even be an alias of the same server, so long as it looks different to the browser). Note that doing so will prevent **your** JavaScript code from accessing it as well. :-)

Comment: Thank you for falsifying my doubts and explanation how to achieve the same effect. Your answer is perfect.